# RxJava - use it for global jobs in a save way

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

If I want something to run and finish regardless of a lifecycle and subscribers, is following the correct way to do it?

I create a singleton and run a "Job" from it like following:

```
public void clearImageCache() {
    Single.fromCallable(() -> {
                ImageManager.clearCacheFromBackground();
                return true;
            }
    )
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(ignored -> {
                // finished
            }, error -> {
                // error
            });
}
```

Is the above way of using `RxJava` for background work that is independent from activities and lifecycles fine? I want it to finish in any case. I think this should be save and should finish, if the application is not destroyed. Is it ok to do it like this or am I missing something here that I should take care of?

I'm not talking care of the returned `Disposable` but I think that's fine as I never want to unsubscribe.

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine until your app is not killed from the memory i.e. swiped from recent tasks, forced stop or killed by os. Also, you should `subscribeOn` on `Schedulers.io()` as it will take load of main thread and keep the UI smooth.